# Publish over file system fails for ASP.NET site when "copy always" selected for Copy to Output Directory

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, publish

I've got an ASP.NET web application in which I recently added a Crystal Report.  I have my build action set to "None".  When Copy to Output Directory is set to "Do Not Copy" the project builds and publishes fine.  When I change the copy option to "Copy Always" the publish action always fails every time.  If I switch it back to "Do Not Copy" then the publish starts working again.

Has anybody else run into this problem and know how to solve it?

thanks,

Jeff Balcerzak

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Does it give you any more specific detail? Did you stop the application pool in IIS before attempting to deploy?

Comment: In the publish window in VS 2015 it says "publish failed" and nothing is copied.  I've never had to stop the application pool in IIS before.  Right now, I've resorted to copying up the .rpt file manually to my production server, but there's got to be a way for the publish wizard to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can try with this procedure, it might be helpful.